# Symfony Choice assertion message override

Tags: php, symfony, validation, assert

I have this assertion inside my entity :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"fiction", "non-fiction"}, message = "Choose a valid genre.")
 */
protected $genre;
```

And the documentation says for the **message** parameter :

> **type**: string
>
> **default**: The value you selected is not a valid choice.
>
> This is the message that you will receive **if the multiple option is set to false** and the underlying value is not in the valid array of choices.

And in my form type, I have :

```
->add('genre', ChoiceType::class, [
    'multiple' => false,
])
```

But, when the value of **gender** field isn't in the valid array of choices ("fiction", "non-fiction"), the message error is "This value is not valid."

It isn't not the default value, nor the value I set in the entity.

I know I can override it in the form type with the "**invalid_message**" parameter,
but I want to if there is an explanation on this ?

Why the "**message**" parameter oth the Assert/Choice doesn't work?
How can I make it work like its expected in the symfony [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#message) ?

Comment: Try to set multiple to true, since the error says that "This is the message that you will receive if the multiple option is set to false..." just a simple remark

Comment: As I understand it, the message we set in the Assert/Choice **message** attribute IS the message we get if multiple is set to false, as it is in my exemple. I also tried with multiple to true but the message is always "**This value is not valid.**"

Answer (score 0):

In the docs, it's not speficied that you can pass the possible values in this place.
You need to create a function in the class (for example "getGender()") that returns an array with the valid values.
Then, with the assert, you can call this function like this :

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Choice(callback = "getGender", message = "Choose a valid genre.")
     */
    protected $genre;

    public function getGender() {
        return array("fiction", "non-fiction");
    }
}
```

And be carefull, you used "choices" instead of "callback" in the annotation ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but in the doc its specified to pass choices directly via the choices option (see **Basic Usage** paragraph). But I also tried with a callback function and as I expected I have the same behavior : message validation is not what I explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

My first remark would be that 
`/**
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"fiction", "non-fiction"}, message = "Choose a valid genre.")
 */
protected $genre;`
attribute's name is genre but on the form type you're calling it gender.
I guess this is just mistyping problem.
Just rename the attribute gender instead of genre .

Comment: Sorry, its a typo error in my question. In my code its the same name of course. I edited the 1st post. Thanks.